# installing database engine without admin rights

Tags: c#, vb.net, ms-access

I have a project with `vb-2013` and my database is `access 2013`.
When I run my project on another computer this error appears:

> Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not registered on the local
>   machine error

Is there a way to install a Microsoft database engine without admin rights because of security policies
or
adding any `dll` file to my project to run it without installing Microsoft database engine.

Answer (score 4):

Not to my knowledge, no. All ODBC and OLE-DB driver binary registrations are handled by systemwide controls. ODBC does allow for per-user connection settings, it still requires systemwide binary installation. If you're writing a "portable" (installation-free) application I recommmend using Sqlite instead.

As an aside, there are very few reasons to use JET Red (MS Access) today over actively-developed systems like Sqlite considering how limited the tooling is, and how SQL implementation is non-standard (e.g. it doesn't support `COALESCE` and it also requires a parenthesis pair around every `JOIN`) .